# Executing docker from terminal directly works fine but not when executed from inside a .sh script?

Tags: bash, docker, ubuntu

I am on ubuntu 20.04 I installed docker using `sudo snap install docker` now when I run directly from the terminal (terminal installed with ubuntu) docker command it works fine but when I execute a .sh script from the terminal using either bash ./script.sh or ./script.sh I am getting an error docker: command not found.

This is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
source $(cd "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")" && pwd)/env.sh

docker run -e "NODE_ENV=dev" -it --rm --name my-npm-2 -v $PROJECT_HOME/code:/var/www/html/code -w /var/www/html/code node:14 npm install

docker run -e "NODE_ENV=dev" -it --rm --name my-npm -v $PROJECT_HOME/code/web:/var/www/html/code/web -w /var/www/html/code/web node:14 npm install


$SCRIPT_HOME/buildjs_dev.sh

docker exec project_php sudo php -d memory_limit=-1 /usr/local/bin/composer install --working-dir=/var/www/html/code


docker exec project_php chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/code/var/cache
docker exec project_php chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/code/var/log
```

I am new to linux in general and I don't know if the problem is with the script itself or why isn't it recognizing docker?

Comment: Those `npm install` and `composer install` commands seems like they should normally be run in your image's Dockerfile, not via a debugging interface like `docker exec`.  Do you have Dockerfiles for your Javascript and PHP applications that you could `docker build`?

Comment: Can you place this command `echo $PATH` right after `#!/bin/bash` and and before first docker command and share these 2 output. Your PATH even may be changed due to your first source command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining a source file at the start of your script which might be changing the PATH variable. Try by either commenting the source line or calling the docker command with full path.